# Full Calendar Anywhere click event on date column

Tags: javascript, jquery

In full calendar javascript i want to show event details on click ,but it is working for day click similarly i want to return same result on event click . how can i do in easiest way i just want the same result as day click on click of event also.

Comment: You need to show us some code. What have you tried?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: dayClick: function(date) {
     var dayOfMonth=1;
     var fromDate=date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+dayOfMonth)+"/"+date.getFullYear();
     var toDate=date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+dayOfMonth)+"/"+date.getFullYear();
      var attr = "fetchMarkerDetails.action?&"+ $("#bookingSearchForm").serialize()+"&fromDate=" + fromDate +"&toDate=" + toDate;
      jQuery.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: attr,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(response) {
                  }

Comment: I am currently using dayClick function which is working fine but only on click of particular calendar date but i am showing event also there on click of that event area it is not working.

Comment: eventSources : [                                 { 
                                        url : "fetchCalendarDetails.action?"+$("#selected-tab").val() + "&" + $('#bookingSearchForm').serialize(), 
                                        type : 'POST', 
                                        error : function() { 
                                              //  alert('Error !.. While Fetching Calendar Details!'); 
                                        },
                                ],

Comment: fetching calendar details from eventsource